# Wrong TileMap coordinates on zoom with InputEventScreenTouch

Tags: godot

The goal is to enable the player to drow the patch for the character.
So I start with simple think, set value for cell(0, 0) in tilemap

[image]

and replace the value when the user clicks on it

[image]

and it works as expected.

But when I change the camera zoom and try it again it set value in another cell:

[image]

I was trying to multiple/divide the click position by the zoom value but it also not resolve the problem

Can anyone give me the hint on how should I handle that?

repo: [Github](https://github.com/Alcadur/the_labyrinth_game/tree/zoom-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you zoom, the coordinates you get from the input event (screen coordinates) do not match the world.

If you have an input event, the recommended way to do this is with [`make_input_local`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_canvasitem.html#class-canvasitem-method-make-input-local):

```
tilemap.world_to_map(tilemap.make_input_local(event).position)
```

However, if you don't, but you have screen coordinates, you can do this:

```
var transform = tilemap.get_canvas_transform() * tilemap.get_global_transform()
tilemap.world_to_map(transform.affine_inverse() * screen_coordinates)
```